# Can open and close div, but not open again

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify

I'm using the timber time by Shopify on my Shopify Store. I added this code to make a div with ajaxed cart open and close.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').on('click', '.cart-show', function (e) {
        $("#cart").hide();
    });
});
```

This works, but when you open and close it, it can not be opened again. Anybody know why?

[Live view.](http://eldeskin.com/products/hydrating-moisture-cream) Make sure to add a product to see the cart.

Also if somebody knows how to use Shopify Timber theme, anybody know how to style the empty cart page? Can't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

There's no reason your cart would show again, you're only calling `hide` on it. Change this to `toggle`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').on('click', '.cart-show', function (e) {
        $("#cart").toggle();
    });
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: This doesn't work. When using toggle it can be removed once. But not opened again.

Answer (score -1):

you can use toggle and other animation effect provided by Jquery,eg slideUp and slideDown

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').on('click', '.cart-show', function (e) {
        $("#cart").slideUp();

    });
});
```

ref http://api.jquery.com/slideup/